# Why am I getting the value for the integral I = $2\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1.dt}{e^{t^{2}}+1} = -1$

Tags: integration, limits, number-theory

(The above integral is derived from the integral for the Dirichlet eta function for Eta(1/2))

While solving for the integral
$$
I = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1.dt}{e^{t^{2}} + 1}
$$

Considering the numerator as u and denominator as v, I used Integration by parts. I specifically used the Integration by parts identity

$$
\int\frac{u.dx}{v} = \int\frac{v.du - u.dv}{v(x)^{2}} 
$$

In my case, I get
$$
2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{[(1+e^{t^{2}}).0 - 1.(2te^{t^{2}})].dt}{(e^{t^{2}}+1)^{2}}
$$

$$
= -2\int_{}^{\infty}\frac{2te^{t^{2}}.dt}{(e^{t^{2}}+1)^{2}}
$$

Taking $e^{t^{2}} + 1 = k$ and $2te^{t^{2}}.dt$ as $dk$, we get

$$
= -2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dk}{k^{2}}
$$

$$
= -2\left|\frac{-1}{k}\right|_{0}^\infty
$$

Substituting the original equation $k = e^{x} + 1$ We get,

$$
= -2\left|\frac{-1}{e^{t^{2}}+1}\right|_{0}^\infty
$$

We first apply the limit to $\infty$
$$
= \lim_{t \to \infty} -2\left|\frac{-1}{e^{t^{2}}+1}\right|
$$

Which is equal to 0

Similarly applying the limit to 0, we get

$$
= -\lim_{t \to 0} -2\left|\frac{-1}{e^{t^{2}}+1}\right|
$$

which is equal to -1

Did I make a mistake, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Please specify the limits of integrations everywhere.

Comment: I added the limits. Sorry I overlooked it.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the derivation of that “identity” and the hypotheses under which it holds.

Comment: I derived the integral from the Integral for Dirichlet eta function for s = 1/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your identity is a mess. You can use the quotient rule with integration by parts, but you have to do it correctly.

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac uv\,dx &= x\frac uv\Big|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty x\left(\frac uv\right)'\,dx = x\frac uv\Big|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty x\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}\,dx \\ &= x\frac uv\Big|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty x\frac{v\,du - u\,dv}{v^2}.
\end{align*}

Indeed, your boundary terms disappear (although you never verified that) but your integration is off by a sign and by integrating with a product with $t$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll have to strengthen my fundamentals first.